# replace the multiple occurence of a variable at the start of a string using JSTL?

Tags: jstl

var1 = "PPPP1234P56"

I need to replace the "P" at the start and then store it in a variable "var2" using JSTL.

o/p needed at var2 ="1234P56"

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

here's a sample code that will check and remove a part of a string with multiple copies at the start of a string

```
String var1 = "PPPP1234P56";
                    String firstchar = var1.substring(0);
                    String replaceme = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < var1.length(); i++) {
                        if (firstchar.equals(firstchar)) {
                            replaceme = replaceme.concat(firstchar);
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    String var2 = var1.replace(replaceme, "");
```